# TypeError: Vue.component is not a function laravel project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

This seems it is a persistent problem. I searched all over for solutions with no success yet. I'll just post the exact error message from my console:

```
app.js:34588 Uncaught TypeError: Vue.component is not a function
at Object.supportsPassive (app.js:34588)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:12599)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
at Object.defineProperty.value (app.js:12588)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:20)
at app.js:63
at app.js:66
```

and now my package.json:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "vue": "^2.5.7"
},
"dependencies": {
    "vee-validate": "^2.1.0-beta.9",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuetify": "^1.2.3",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
}
```

app.js

```html
import Vue from 'vue'
import './plugins/bootstrap'
import './plugins/vuetify'
import router from './plugins/routes'

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */
// Vue.component('entry', require('./pages/Home.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
});
```

Comment: `vue` should **not** be a dev-dependency. In fact, I doubt anything there should be a dev-dependency except for maybe laravel-mix and cross-env

Comment: So what does your code in `app.js` look like?

Comment: You need to import Vue, ie `import Vue from 'vue'`. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: imported in the bootstrap file

Comment: That does not import the `Vue` symbol into `app.js` though. When using modules, you need to import everything required. I don't understand why you're assigning `Vue` to `window` or mixing `import` and `require` either. Seems quite odd

Comment: Let me change it

Comment: still no success yet, changed my app.js to: see the edit question above please

Comment: And are you still getting the same error? Typically in a Vue CLI setup, you import your single-file components. If you're trying to use lazy-loaded / async components, your syntax is slightly off. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components

Comment: still the same error. and about the link you provided, that shows async loading of components, my issue actually I think is to do with global registration. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Global-Registration

Comment: Your code doesn't match your error message at all. The error says _"`Vue.component` is not a function"_ at line 66 but a) your `app.js` file is nowhere near that long, and b) the only call to `Vue.component` is commented out

Comment: app js becomes that long after the other files have been imported into the app.js.

Comment: just a quick mention, Vue.component from the browser console also returns undefined

Comment: That doesn't answer the part about the line being commented out. What does your `app.js` file **actually** look like?

Comment: Thanks, Phil, I have looked back after some more searches, I added vue as a cdn and It worked, what could this mean, Do I have to install vue again? or was my installation wrong. I had installed via npm

Comment: Is it a browser caching issue? Add `.version()` as the last build step in your laravel.mix.js to be sure it's not a browser caching issue

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I was making some dependecies updates on a laravel 7 project and it started to see this error on vue compiled views. I change the Vue package call:

> Use `import Vue from 'vue'` instead of `window.Vue = require("vue");` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Vue.js so I will share how I got my app running. I am using Laravel 9 and Vue 3. My code was as follows:

```
// import Vue from 'vue';
import {
    createApp
} from 'vue';

const app = createApp({});

Vue.component('mainapp', require('./components/mainapp.vue').default)

app.mount('#app');
```

This gave the following error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'component')

So, I did a console.log(Vue) and I got `undefined`. I then changed to

`app.component('mainapp', require('./components/mainapp.vue').default)`

and it worked!